# How to reset the built-in Dictionary app for Look Up function?

Tags: dictionary

After I downloaded some custom dictionaries, copy-paste them into `~/Library/Dictionaries` folder, and reordered them in Dictionary app's `Preferences`, some options in the `Preferences` cannot be selected anymore (the check-sign cannot be selected, it blinks). How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like one of the dictionaries is causing problems. Try removing all the ones you've added and then install them one at a time, checking the options.

Comment: @benwiggy: I'm trying reinstalling the macOS to solve this problem... I don't know where to download those built-in dictionaries.

Comment: Just remove those you‘ve installed manually, reboot and see whether this helps. Reinstalling the OS for this seems to be a rather extreme measure.

Comment: @nohillside: Actually I only added and deleted those custom dictionaries and no touch anything else, and I did try reboot, but the problem remains. I also thought reinstalling the OS a bad idea, but I cannot find the solution for this problem... Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug specific to MacBook Pro 16-inch with Catalina 10.15.X (In my case X=2), **so reinstall the OS will not help**. If you're in the same situation, I can solve this problem for you as follows, which is my conclusion from [the Apple Communities thread discussing the same problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250861549):

1. Remove all folders under `/System/Library/AssetsV2/PreinstalledAssetsV2/InstallWithOs/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX`.
2. Restart your computer. (In my case the Look Up didn't show some dictionary definition before I restarted my computer.)